# chrome freezes with this ext.each

Tags: extjs

I have extended the backend in Shopware. And the given Ext.each freezes chrome.

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Order.view.detail.PrintOverview', {
override: 'Shopware.apps.Order.view.detail.Overview',



initComponent:function () {
    var me = this;
    me.callParent(arguments);
    var printconfig = JSON.parse("{$printconfig|@json_encode}");
    /**
     * check if one position is from print24
     */
    Ext.each(me.record.getPositionsStore.data.items, function (obj) {
        if (Ext.Array.contains(printconfig, obj.data.md_supplier)){
            var newContainer = me.createPrintContainer();
            Ext.Array.insert(me.items.items, 1, [newContainer]);
            return false;
        }
    });
},
```

....

There should be added a new container, if the value of obj.data.md_supplier is in the array printconfig. IN debugger it runs very well.
Any idea ?
Maybe it is not allowed here in initComponent()

ADDED:

```
Ext.Array.insert(me.items.items, 1, [newContainer]);
```

is doing the problem. But I do not know why, because I did it like it is done in other plugins og shopware.

Original InitComponent():

```
     */
initComponent:function () {
    var me = this;

    me.registerEvents();
    me.items = [
        me.createConvertOrderContainer(),
        me.createCustomerNotification(),
        me.createCustomerInformation(),
        me.createDetailsContainer(),
        me.createEditContainer(),
        me.createAttributeForm(),
    ];
    me.dockedItems = [me.createToolbar()];
    me.callParent(arguments);
    me.detailsForm.loadRecord(me.record);
    me.editForm.loadRecord(me.record);
    me.attributeForm.loadAttribute(me.record.get('id'));
},
```

my extension:

```
    initComponent:function () {
    var me = this;
    var items  = me.callParent();
     return Ext.Array.insert(items ,1,[me.createPrint24Container()]);
},
```

But it is still the same

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"? It causes the browser to crash? It throws an exception? It's slow and causes the browser to hang momentarily?

Comment: At first chrome shows the output right. But then chrome is not doing anything. I have to close it manually in the taskmanager.
No exception

Comment: It happend, when I want to close the panel

Comment: then firefox shows "script does not answer"

Comment: What does createPrintContainer() do ? Does it call some sync api ?

Comment: At the moment an empty Panel

the prob is anywhere else. I set it back to the original and I still have the freezing.

Comment: The call to `insert()` is entirely wrong, you can't manipulate the underlying data structure of the collection. Use the container methods (add/insert) for a start.

Comment: Ok. You said it is just for a start, but how should I extend me.items ? That's the way it is done in shopware plugins

Comment: OK I unserstood. But the new container should be between first and second.But first container is type of hbox and the second is collapsed. So how do I get a a new container in a single row between both ?

Comment: thx. I got it. I put a container around it. Thx for your help